# Is electrolysis of molten silver nitrate possible?

Tags: redox, electrolysis

Since the salt is molten, the only ions are $\ce{Ag+}$ and $\ce{NO3-}$, and both of them can only do a reduction reaction. Who goes to the anode? Also, there is no acid in the solution — only the salt — therefore the following reaction cannot occur, right?

$$\ce{ NO3- + 4H+ + 3e- -> NO + H2O}$$

So, what happens? The only possible reaction is the reduction of the $\ce{Ag+}$ to $\ce{Ag (s)}$. There is literally nothing else.

Comment: You can't have reduction without oxidation.  Then again, who said they can only do a reduction reaction?

Comment: Why oxygen shouldn't evolve?

Comment: @IvanNeretin the nitrogen and the silver already have their highest oxidation numbers.

Comment: True, but are they the only elements here?

Comment: Then you might want to read the formula again: AgNO3. Still no other elements besides Ag and N?

Comment: but what's the potential: O(2-) = 1/2 O2 + 2e(-)? How do I know this is the non-spontaneous reaction?

Comment: Well, if it were spontaneous, then AgNO3 would not _exist_ in the first place, would it?

Comment: $\ce{NO3- + Ag+ -> NO + O2 + Ag(0)}$ is a balanced reaction. Based on published half-reaction potentials, you should be able to work out the thermodynamics of the overall reaction.

Comment: @Andrew I'd opt for NO2 (not that it matters much). More importantly, the published potentials are for water solutions, and hence useless.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin that's pretty obvious i just want to know if the electrolysis can actually happen. Im now convinced it can but we can't calculate the potential to apply to the cell, and the reaction forms O2 at the anode and Ag at the cathode

Comment: That's right. Molten AgNO3 is a pretty exotic medium, so I wouldn't expect the potentials to be readily available in the reference books. Chemistry is an experimental science, people say.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, a nitrate reduction in the presence or silver ions only would have to give silver oxide; but this [decomposes between 200 and 300°C](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_oxide).  So, perforce, you would ultimately get elemental silver from electrolyzing the nitrate melt.

However, that does not mean it's best.  With a little additional heating, to 440°C, you [get decomposition to elemental silver just with the heating](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_nitrate).